# Create NumberLong integer using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Integer value in mongodb document its saving 32int.
I want to save 64bit values in mongodb.

**code is here:**

```
import time
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_database
data = {}
data['num'] = 100
data['createAt'] = datetime.datetime.now()
curTime = datetime.datetime.now()
curTime =  int(time.mktime(curTime.timetuple()))
data['time'] = curTime
db.test.insert(data)
```

**Result:**

```
{ 
     "_id" : ObjectId("583420ce7e60a74345c97624"), 
     "num" : NumberInt(100), 
     "createAt" : ISODate("2016-11-22T15:41:18.773+0000"), 
     "time" : NumberInt(1479811278) 
}
```

**Wanted result is:**

```
{ 
     "_id" : ObjectId("583420ce7e60a74345c97624"), 
     "num" : NumberLong(100), 
     "createAt" : ISODate("2016-11-22T15:41:18.773+0000"), 
     "time" : NumberLong(1479811278) 
}
```

***its stored in NumberInt rather than NumberLong***

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to explicitly create your `NumberLong` variable using the `bson.Int64` type.

```
import bson

data['num'] = bson.Int64(100)
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on [user3100115's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100115/user3100115) answer, I read PyMongo `BSON` `int64` [docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/int64.html).

The correct usage to create a `NumberLong` is bson.**int64**.Int64

```
import bson

number_long = bson.int64.Int64(100)
```